# sparql select multiple count return different results

Tags: count, sparql

I run the following queries in **Protégé** on the same data

```
SELECT (COUNT(?VM) AS ?count_VM) 
WHERE {
    ?VM a cocoon:VM .
}
```

Correctly gives me 57

`SELECT (COUNT(?storage) AS ?count_storage)
WHERE {
    ?storage a cocoon:Storage .
}`

Correctly gives me 8

**But**

`SELECT (COUNT(?VM) AS ?count_VM) (COUNT(?storage) AS ?count_storage)
WHERE {
    ?VM a cocoon:VM .
    ?storage a cocoon:Storage .
}`

gives me

`"456"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>`

for both `?count_VM` and `?count_storage`

what's wrong?

Comment: 57×8=456, you have "Cartesian product" (all possible combinations) of results produced by two independent patterns. Possibly you need `{ ?VM a cocoon:VM . ?VM a cocoon:Storage } `.

Comment: you mean `{
    ?VM a cocoon:VM .
    ?storage a cocoon:Storage
}` without the dot at the end? it doesn't change the result

Comment: `?VM` instead of `?storage`. If you just want to sum results, use `UNION` or  `VALUES`. E.g. `SELECT (count(?s) AS ?count) {
    ?s a ?type . VALUES (?type){(cocoon:VM) (cocoon:storage)}
}`.

Comment: Actually, I just want the count of each class, can I put them in one query, or do I have to run each individually?

Comment: Nested `SELECT`s. E. g. `select * {
  {select (count(?storage) AS ?count_storage){
  ?storage wdt:P31 cocoon:storage .
  }}
  {select (count(?VM) AS ?count_VM) {
  ?VM wdt:P31 cocoon:VM .
  }
  }
}`

Comment: it gives me 0 for Storage, see updated question.

Comment: Please excuse my typos, obviously, you should use `a` instead of `wdt:P31` and `Storage` instead of `storage` :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better answer by [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw):

```
select ?cls (count(?s) AS ?count)
{VALUES ?cls {cocoon:Storage cocoon:VM} ?s a ?cls}
group by ?cls
```

---

Old answer by [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin):

```
select * { 
    {
        select (count(?storage) AS ?count_storage)
        { ?storage a cocoon:Storage . }
    } 
    {
        select (count(?VM) AS ?count_VM) 
        { ?VM a cocoon:VM . } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: why are you not using `VALUES` to get one row for the count of each class you'Re interested in? `select ?cls (count(?s) AS ?count) {VALUES ?cls {cocoon:Storage cocoon:VM} ?s a ?cls} group by ?cls`